# tiles for offline telerik wpf map

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

**Problem Summary**

I am trying to create an offline tiled map for a WPF application that uses telerik. The user does not need to zoom in very far. I am having trouble finding a source of tiles that can be implemented with telerik.

**What I've tried**

I am using [RadMap](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radmap/overview) from telerik for WPF. They have an option for implementing tiles from a custom tile provider. I have been trying to follow the solutions given in [this forum](https://www.telerik.com/forums/offline-tiledmapprovider) and [this forum.](https://www.telerik.com/forums/offline-map-server) They recommend downloading tiles from [Easy OpenStreetMap Downloader](http://allmapsoft.com/openstreetmap/), but it the file format does not match the code. It appears in the code, the tiles should be grouped in folders according to zoom level, then in a folder according to x coordinate. However, it looks to me like openstreetmaps downloader groups them by y coordinate only. I either need to get openstreetmaps downloader to save the tiles in this format, or to find another provider that will.

**Code**

Here is the telerik code that I am trying to base my solution off of:

```
/// <summary>
/// Tile source which read map tiles from the file system.
/// </summary>
public class FileSystemTileSource : TiledMapSource
{
    private string tilePathFormat;
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the FileSystemTileSource class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tilePathFormat">Format string to access tiles in file system.</param>
    public FileSystemTileSource(string tilePathFormat)
        : base(1, 20, 256, 256)
    {
        this.tilePathFormat = tilePathFormat;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize provider.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        // Raise provider intialized event.
        this.RaiseIntializeCompleted();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the image URI.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tileLevel">Tile level.</param>
    /// <param name="tilePositionX">Tile X.</param>
    /// <param name="tilePositionY">Tile Y.</param>
    /// <returns>URI of image.</returns>
    protected override Uri GetTile(int tileLevel, int tilePositionX, int tilePositionY)
    {
        int zoomLevel = ConvertTileToZoomLevel(tileLevel);
        string tileFileName = this.tilePathFormat.Replace("{zoom}", zoomLevel.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        tileFileName = tileFileName.Replace("{x}", tilePositionX.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        tileFileName = tileFileName.Replace("{y}", tilePositionY.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        if (File.Exists(tileFileName))
        {
            return new Uri(tileFileName);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
/// <summary>
/// Map provider which read map tiles from the file system.
/// </summary>
public class FileSystemProvider : TiledProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MyMapProvider class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tilePathFormat">Format string to access tiles in file system.</param>
    public FileSystemProvider(string tilePathFormat)
        : base()
    {
        FileSystemTileSource source = new FileSystemTileSource(tilePathFormat);
        this.MapSources.Add(source.UniqueId, source);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the SpatialReference for the map provider.
    /// </summary>
    public override ISpatialReference SpatialReference
    {
        get
        {
            return new MercatorProjection();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.radMap.Provider = new FileSystemProvider("Path to OpenStreet Images\\{zoom}\\{x}\\os_{x}_{y}_{zoom}.png");
}
```

Comment: You can download the tile images from `https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` and organize them as you like. Note that the `User-Agent`  HTTP header of your requests has to be set, otherwise the tile server won't serve your requests.